# Which VMWare should I choose?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm new to VMWare stuff. What I need to do is pretty basic: Just to install two different Windows 2008 versions on a server with  2x 4core CPU and 2x 3TB hard disks.

I asked my datacenter to install the free version  (VMware ESXi 4.1) but apparently it did not recognize 3TB disks. Now I'm wondering whether VMWare  5 can handle 3TB disks, and if so, what variant? There is a huge array of options there and some prices are astonishingly high:
http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/pricing.html

So I'm really confused and I appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 1):

vSphere 5.1 supports 3TB disks. You can register and download free ESXi [here](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=free-esxi5&lp=default).

Comment: VMFS datastores are still limited to a 2TB extents so .vmdks can only be that size (RDMs can be up to 64TB) so you'd still need to carve up that 3TB into 2+1, 1.5+1.5 or similar arrangements, it won't like a single 3TB LUN at all.